# Stripe Checkout - Is it possible to have more than one image show up on the checkout page?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

In the below line_items.items.price_data.product_data.images array, I input two images, however only one shows. Is there a way to see two images on the checkout page?

```
app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
  const domainURL = process.env.DOMAIN;

  const { quantity, locale } = req.body;

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: process.env.PAYMENT_METHODS.split(', '),
    mode: 'payment',
    locale: locale,
    line_items: [
      {
        // price: process.env.PRICE,
        price_data: {
          currency: 'usd',
          unit_amount: 1000,
          product_data: {
            name: 'Product name ...',
            images: [
              'https://picsum.photos/280/320?random=4',
              'https://picsum.photos/280/320?random=2',
            ],
          },
        },
        quantity: quantity,
        description: 'My description ...',
      },
    ],
    success_url: `${domainURL}/success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    cancel_url: `${domainURL}/canceled.html`,
  });

  res.send({
    sessionId: session.id,
  });
});
```

The documentation (https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data-product_data-images) suggests that I can:

> ```
> line_items.price_data.product_data.images
> optional
> A list of up to 8 URLs of images for this product, meant to be displayable to the customer.
> ```

... but it doesn't work when I add two; only the first in the array shows.

Comment: I think Checkout can only show one image today, so only the first works, as you've found. `line_items.price_data` is shared more generally in the API and is fairly generic, but yeah, the documentation isn't very clear here.

Comment: @karllekko, judging from your profile, you've been using Stripe for a long time. Anything you recommend for learning the platform inside and out? The documentation is really good, but not great for someone new to Stripe.

Comment: I use Stripe's APIs and products everyday so I've built up familiarity with them. I'd suggest just starting small and scoping out only the part you need(like here where you're using Checkout) and trying to understand that whole area. The concepts then apply to other products(like Prices and LineItems here are also used for Invoices/Subscriptions) if you expand your integration in those directions. You can also ask Stripe's support or their IRC channel any clarifying questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted customer support today (8/17/2020) and according to Stripe, "Stripe Checkout" only allows for one image at checkout and does not support a custom domain ... when the user is ready to buy, you'll need to redirect him/her to a Stripe URL to complete the payment.

TL;DR:
Stripe Checkout supports one image at checkout and does not support a custom domain.